# What's the best way to count occurences of positive, negative, and 0 values in an unsorted array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, go, optimization

The below works but how would I optimize this? I imagine looping through the array would become expensive as it grows.
I could create a map of the original array to store the number of occurrences for each value and then check those values for +/-/0 in another loop but that's even worse.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr := []int{2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, -2, -2, 2, 2, 3, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 2, -3, -7}
    var p, n, z int = 0, 0, 0
    for _, v := range arr {
        if v > 0 {
            p++
        } else if v < 0 {
            n++
        } else if v == 0 {
            z++
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(p, n, z)
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).  ;)  Furthermore  `arr` is *not* an array, but a slice - an apparently small, but interesting difference.

Comment: I don't think you can make the operation of accessing all values in an array any less expensive than a loop. But you can try to make if faster by processing it with multiple goroutines concurrently. Go would try to make use of all the cores to run those goroutines parallelly.

Comment: @KoalaYeung Concurrency != parallelism. ;)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Sure. And I don't think my comment confused the two.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg this wasn't a homework problem I'm just trying to get used to go and have been doing problems like this on hackerrank/leetcode. I was genuinely trying to learn how to do this better. :)

Answer (score 2):

If your input structure is an unsorted array, then O(n) is the best you can do, that is, go through the array, comparing each element once.

You may, if it is an option, work with two arrays and an integer, one array for negatives, one array for positives, and an integer to count the number of zeros. Then, counting would no longer be necessary, and you can simply get the length of the arrays.

Comment: In order to split out the original slice a for loop would still be the only way even after sorting correct?

Comment: If the original slice was sorted, you can use binary search to locate the 0's. If the original slice is not sorted, you have to look at each and every element using a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much at the optimum solution. I implemented @bserdar's suggestion of sorting first and ran a benchmark against it.

> Note: this is an extremely crude implementation. Take it with a pound of salt.

Package and import omitted for readability.

```golang
var slice = []int{2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, -2, -2, 2, 2, 3, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 2, -3, -7}

func orig(s []int) (negative, zero, positive int) {
    for _, v := range s {
        if v > 0 {
            positive++
        } else if v < 0 {
            negative++
        } else if v == 0 {
            zero++
        }
    }
    return
}

func sorted(s []int) (negative, zero, positive int) {
    // We do not want to modify the input slice,
    // so we need to create a copy of it
    sortedSlice := make([]int, len(s))
    copy(sortedSlice, s)
    sort.Ints(sortedSlice)
    return preSorted(sortedSlice)
}

func preSorted(s []int) (int, int, int) {
    var z, p int
    var zfound bool
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] < 0 {
            continue
        } else if !zfound && s[i] == 0 {
            zfound = true
            z = i
        } else if s[i] > 0 {
            p = i
            break
        }
    }
    return z, p - z, len(s) - p
}
```

The test code:

```golang
func BenchmarkOrig(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        orig(slice)
    }
}

func BenchmarkLongOrig(b *testing.B) {
    var slice = make([]int, 10000000)
    for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
        slice[i] = rand.Intn(10)
        if rand.Intn(2) == 0 {
            slice[i] = slice[i] * -1
        }
    }
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        orig(slice)
    }
}
func BenchmarkSorted(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        sorted(slice)
    }
}

func BenchmarkLongSorted(b *testing.B) {
    var slice = make([]int, 10000000)
    for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
        slice[i] = rand.Intn(10)
        if rand.Intn(2) == 0 {
            slice[i] = slice[i] * -1
        }
    }
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        sorted(slice)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPresorted(b *testing.B) {
    cp := make([]int, len(slice))
    copy(cp, slice)
    sort.Ints(cp)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        preSorted(cp)
    }
}

func BenchmarkLongPresorted(b *testing.B) {
    var slice = make([]int, 10000000)
    for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ {
        slice[i] = rand.Intn(10)
        if rand.Intn(2) == 0 {
            slice[i] = slice[i] * -1
        }
    }
    sort.Ints(slice)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        sorted(slice)
    }
}
```

The according benchmark:

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkOrig-4             27271665            38.4 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLongOrig-4               21      50343196 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkSorted-4            1405150           852 ns/op         272 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkLongSorted-4              2     536973066 ns/op    80003104 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkPresorted-4        100000000           10.9 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLongPresorted-4           5     248698010 ns/op    80003104 B/op          2 allocs/op
```

**EDIT** Found a slightly more efficient way of returning the count. Instead of creating new slices, we calculate the length of each subslice. That makes a presorted very efficient when the slice is smaller. But at 10M, simply counting seems to be the most efficient.

qed

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to:

a) make sure the array/slice is using the smallest data type possible (to reduce the amount of RAM and number of cache lines touched; to pack more values into a single SIMD register, and to reduce the amount of shifting I'm going to suggest later) - e.g. for the values you've shown in the question you could/should be using `int8` (and not `int`).

b) add zeros to the end to pad the array/slice to a multiple of however many elements the CPU can do at once using SIMD (e.g. 32 elements if you're using `int8` on an 80x86 CPU that supports AVX2). This mostly just avoids a messy hassle when you get near the end of the array/slice.

c) using SIMD in a loop:

- load a group of values into a SIMD register
- copy the group to another SIMD register
- use "unsigned shift right" then "AND" on the entire group of numbers so that the lowest bit in each number contains the original number's sign bit
- add the result of this to a "group of counters of negative numbers" in a different SIMD register
- use a sequence of "shift" and "OR", to merge all bits of a number into a single bit, to get "1 if original number was non-zero, 0 if original numbers was zero"
- add the result of this to a "group of counters of non-zero numbers" in a different SIMD register

d) After all that (outside the loop):

- calculate the count of negative numbers by doing a "horizontal add" of the "group of counters of negative numbers"
- calculate the count of positive numbers by doing a "horizontal add" of the "group of counters of non-zero numbers", then subtracting the count of negative numbers
- calculate the count of zeros by doing "zeros = all_numbers - negative_numbers - positive_numbers - padding_zeros"

Of course to do anything well you need inline assembly, which means that you'll want something like https://godoc.org/github.com/slimsag/rand/simd (that does the inline assembly for you in a nice portable way).

Note 1: for large arrays/slices (but not small arrays/slices) you'll also want to use multiple CPUs in parallel (e.g. have N threads/goroutines if there's N CPUs, and split the array/slice into N pieces where each thread/goroutine does one piece, then add the counts from each piece before doing "step d)").

Note 2: For larger amounts of data; my algorithm is "O(n)", and because your original algorithm is only "O(n)" I'd expect my algorithm to be up to 100 times faster on modern hardware. However, for very small amounts of data, because "O(n)" is not linear, I'd expect your algorithm to be faster than mine.